# How to select multiple document references in a single query?

Tags: javascript, performance, google-cloud-firestore, non-relational-database

I have two Firestore collections, one called `parents` and one called `children`. These collections are "related" in that `parents` have an array of `child` document references attached to them.

**What I want to accomplish is:** Get all `children` that are "related" to a single `parent` in a performant way.

**What I tried:** I came up with this code that works great functionally:

```js
this.subscription = this.props.firebase.parent().onSnapshot((parent) => { // get a single parent

    let childrenPromises = (parent.data().children || []).map(child => this.props.firebase.child(child.id).get()); // build array of promises

    Promise.all(childPromises) // resolve all promises
        .then(children => {
            // children.data() has the data I need :)
        });
});
```

**To summarize:** I retrieve the list of `child` document references, and then using promises retrieve all of them individually. This works great, but bombards my db with query requests.

**What I want to improve:** Can I refactor this somehow into a single, more performant query? Ideally, it would be a single query to prevent so many requests against the db.

**What I have tried:** I have read through all of the Firestore docs and Stack Overflow posts I could find with no luck. I did read that de-normalizing the db is an option, but I would rather not, since multiple `parents` can by tied to `children`.

Any help or advice here is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible to query across differently-named collections in a single query.  There is no "join" type operation.

What are you are doing now is not really "bombarding" Firestore.  It is built to keep up with many document reads, and all queries are pipelined over a single connection.  There is not really an issue with performance or scalability here, unless you are requesting more data than you need.  In fact, Cloud Firestore will simply not allow you to do anything that doesn't scale.  All indexed operations scale massively.

Comment: From the firebase team itself, I guess that answers my question. Thanks so much for confirming this looks ok. As someone from the relational db world I thought it smelled but I guess not!

Comment: If it scales that's great. Is there a place that describes what constitutes as a "read" in the usage statistics? It maters when trying to keep costs low.